# Access a Navigation controller's main view programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a Tab Controller with a navigation controller which has a view, as seen in the image below:

[image: Screen shot of Main.XIB]

I need to retrieve the Switches Controller from within my AppDelegate so I can do some things with it at runtime.

I believe I can retrieve the NavigationController itself by doing this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Not really sure how to access my SwitchesController from there though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make an ivar with an `IBOutlet`? It's probably the most flexible solution as you can now change the ordering of your viewController's without breaking your build.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the `visibleViewController, topViewController` properties of UINaviationController, or call:

```
[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
```

Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope it helps.